# Reset Windows 7 Local Security Policy

Tags: windows-7, windows, security

Is there a way to reset the Local Security Policy on Windows 7? I found how to reset the GPO but not the local. The system is acting weird to where even if you are a Admin you can not uninstall or install .msi packages for example.

Edit: This is Windows Home Premium. Nice of Microsoft to not allow you to edit. -_-

EDIT:
I tried this:

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
```

Stil not luck.

"The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation" is the error message I keep getting.

Comment: The question is what made it act weird to begin with?   If it worked and stopped what caused that?

Comment: No idea. It's not my laptop. Fixing for someone.

Comment: Open a command prompt as administrator and run this command: `for %G in (HKCU,HKLM) do reg query "%G\SOFTWARE\Policies" /s & reg query "%G\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies" /s` Then post here the full output.

Answer (score -2):

You can have a look here "[How do i restore security settings](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/313222)". There is a detailed explanation given. Hope I helped.

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: The link is dead now.